# SpriteKit: suggestions for rounding corners of unconventional grid?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

The goal is to round the corners of an unconventional grid similar to the following:

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/50/bc/e0/50bce0cb908913ebc2cf630d635331ef.jpg

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/7e/29/ee/7e29ee80e957ec22bbba630ccefbfaa2.jpg

Instead of a grid with four corners like a conventional grid, these grids have multiple corners in need of rounding.

The brute force approach would be to identify tiles with corners exposed then round those corners either with a different background image or by clipping the corners in code.

Is there a cleaner approach?

The grid is rendered for an iOS app in a SpriteKit SKScene.

Comment: Nice question, this matrix is at base for many games in commerce.

Comment: can you share a little bit of info about how you layout your grid in the scene editor? how do infer their cords? with name? position? or userData? etc.

Comment: @RonMyschuk not using the scene editor, loading the grid from code as it's dynamic. any suggestions?

Comment: ah, sorry I misunderstood your statement about rendered in Spritekit SKScene. I do have some code that I used to render this exact output, and it's pretty slick. You can make some complex grids and they always look awesome. Not to take away from @AlessandroOrnano answer because he is the man. (and it looks like he put a ton of time into that answer) ;) It's end of work day here so I'll post my answer in the morning.

Comment: @RonMyschuk cool thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did was lay out the tiles then call this function to round the nodes of exposed tiles.

```
// Rounds corners of exposed tiles. UIKit inverts coordinates so top is bottom and vice-versa.
fileprivate func roundTileCorners() {
    // Get all tiles
    var tiles = [TileClass]()
    tileLayer.enumerateChildNodes(withName: ".//*") { node, stop in
        if node is TileClass {
            tiles.append(node as! TileClass)
        }
    }

    // Round corners for each exposed tile
    for t in tiles {
        // Convert tile's position to root coordinates
        let convertedPos = convert(t.position, from: t.parent!)

        // Set neighbor positions
        var leftNeighborPos = convertedPos
        leftNeighborPos.x -= tileWidth
        var rightNeighborPos = convertedPos
        rightNeighborPos.x += tileWidth
        var topNeighborPos = convertedPos
        topNeighborPos.y += tileHeight
        var bottomNeighborPos = convertedPos
        bottomNeighborPos.y -= tileHeight

        // Set default value for rounding
        var cornersToRound : UIRectCorner?

        // No neighbor below & to left? Round bottom left.
        if !isTileAtPoint(point: bottomNeighborPos) && !isTileAtPoint(point: leftNeighborPos) {
            cornersToRound = cornersToRound?.union(.topLeft) ?? .topLeft
        }

        // No neighbor below & to right? Round bottom right.
        if !isTileAtPoint(point: bottomNeighborPos) && !isTileAtPoint(point: rightNeighborPos) {
            cornersToRound = cornersToRound?.union(.topRight) ?? .topRight
        }

        // No neightbor above & to left? Round top left.
        if !isTileAtPoint(point: topNeighborPos) && !isTileAtPoint(point: leftNeighborPos) {
            cornersToRound = cornersToRound?.union(.bottomLeft) ?? .bottomLeft
        }

        // No neighbor above & to right? Round top right.
        if !isTileAtPoint(point: topNeighborPos) && !isTileAtPoint(point: rightNeighborPos) {
            cornersToRound = cornersToRound?.union(.bottomRight) ?? .bottomRight
        }

        // Any corners to round?
        if cornersToRound != nil {
            t.roundCorners(cornersToRound: cornersToRound!)
        }
    }
}

// Returns true if a tile exists at <point>. Assumes <point> is in root node's coordinates.
fileprivate func isTileAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    return nodes(at: point).contains(where: {$0 is BoardTileNode })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a really interesting question.You can build your matrix with different approaches but surely you must resolve everytime the changes about the 4 corners in background for each tiles.

Suppose you start with a `GameViewController` like this (without load `SKS` files and with `anchorPoint` equal to zero):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let view = self.view as! SKView? else { return }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
        let scene = GameScene(size:view.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

My idea is to build a matrix like this:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var sideTile:CGFloat = 40
    private var gridWidthTiles:Int = 5
    private var gridHeightTiles:Int = 6
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.drawMatrix()
    }
    func drawMatrix(){
        var index = 1
        let matrixPos = CGPoint(x:50,y:150)
        for i in 0..<gridHeightTiles {
            for j in 0..<gridWidthTiles {
                let tile = getTile()
                tile.name = "tile\(index)"
                addChild(tile)
                tile.position = CGPoint(x:matrixPos.x+(sideTile*CGFloat(j)),y:matrixPos.y+(sideTile*CGFloat(i)))
                let label = SKLabelNode.init(text: "\(index)")
                label.fontSize = 12
                label.fontColor = .white
                tile.addChild(label)
                label.position = CGPoint(x:tile.frame.size.width/2,y:tile.frame.size.height/2)
                index += 1
            }
        }
    }
    func getTile()->SKShapeNode {
        let tile = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sideTile, height: sideTile), cornerRadius: 10)
        tile.fillColor = .gray
        tile.strokeColor = .gray
        return tile
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Now we can construct a background for each tile of our matrix.
We can made the same tile node but with a different color (maybe more clear than the tile color) and without corner radius. If we split this background in 4 parts we have:

- left - bottom background tile
- left - top background tile
- right - bottom background tile
- right - top background tile

Code for a typical background tile:

```
func getBgTileCorner()->SKShapeNode {
   let bgTileCorner = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sideTile/2, height: sideTile/2))
   bgTileCorner.fillColor = .lightGray
   bgTileCorner.strokeColor = .lightGray
   bgTileCorner.lineJoin = .round
   bgTileCorner.isAntialiased = false
   return bgTileCorner
}
```

Now with the `SKSCropNode` we can obtain only the corner using the background tile and the tile:

```
func getCorner(at angle:String)->SKCropNode {
        let cropNode = SKCropNode()
        let tile = getTile()
        let bgTile = getBgTileCorner() 
        cropNode.addChild(bgTile)
        tile.position = CGPoint.zero
        let tileFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sideTile, height: sideTile)
        switch angle {
            case "leftBottom": bgTile.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x,y:tile.position.y)
            case "rightBottom": bgTile.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x+tileFrame.size.width/2,y:tile.position.y)
            case "leftTop": bgTile.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x,y:tile.position.y+tileFrame.size.height/2)
            case "rightTop": bgTile.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x+tileFrame.size.width/2,y:tile.position.y+tileFrame.size.height/2)
            default:break
        }
        tile.fillColor = self.backgroundColor
        tile.strokeColor = self.backgroundColor
        tile.lineWidth = 0.0
        bgTile.lineWidth = 0.0
        tile.blendMode = .replace
        cropNode.position = CGPoint.zero
        cropNode.addChild(tile)
        cropNode.maskNode = bgTile
        return cropNode
    }
```

**Output** for a typical corner:

```
let corner = getCorner(at: "leftBottom")
addChild(corner)
corner.position = CGPoint(x:50,y:50)
```

[image]

Now we can rebuild the `drawMatrix` function with the corners for each tile:

```
func drawMatrix(){
        var index = 1
        let matrixPos = CGPoint(x:50,y:150)
        for i in 0..<gridHeightTiles {
            for j in 0..<gridWidthTiles {
                let tile = getTile()
                tile.name = "tile\(index)"
                let bgTileLB = getCorner(at:"leftBottom")
                let bgTileRB = getCorner(at:"rightBottom")
                let bgTileLT = getCorner(at:"leftTop")
                let bgTileRT = getCorner(at:"rightTop")
                bgTileLB.name = "bgTileLB\(index)"
                bgTileRB.name = "bgTileRB\(index)"
                bgTileLT.name = "bgTileLT\(index)"
                bgTileRT.name = "bgTileRT\(index)"
                addChild(bgTileLB)
                addChild(bgTileRB)
                addChild(bgTileLT)
                addChild(bgTileRT)
                addChild(tile)
                tile.position = CGPoint(x:matrixPos.x+(sideTile*CGFloat(j)),y:matrixPos.y+(sideTile*CGFloat(i)))
                let label = SKLabelNode.init(text: "\(index)")
                label.fontSize = 12
                label.fontColor = .white
                tile.addChild(label)
                label.position = CGPoint(x:tile.frame.size.width/2,y:tile.frame.size.height/2)
                bgTileLB.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x,y:tile.position.y)
                bgTileRB.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x,y:tile.position.y)
                bgTileLT.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x,y:tile.position.y)
                bgTileRT.position = CGPoint(x:tile.position.x,y:tile.position.y)
                index += 1
            }
        }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Very similar to **your screenshots** (these are two tile example:)

[image]

[image]

Now when you want to remove a tile, you can decide what corner you want to remove or leave because for each tile you have also the relative 4 corners :

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the grid creation process isn't really relative to this. You just need some way of differentiating between a blank spot in the grid and a filled spot. In my example I have a Tile object with a type of .blank or .regular. You need to have all 15 images (you can change the style to whatever you like, although they have to be in the same order and they have to be prefixed with 1..15). It uses bit calculation to figure out which image to use as a background and offsets the background image by 1/2 tile size for x and y. Other than that it is pretty self explanitory. Those background images were my tester images I created when developing this, so feel free to use them.

[image: without background]
    [image: with background]

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]
[image: 8]
[image: 9]
[image: 10]
[image: 11]
[image: 12]
[image: 13]
[image: 14]
[image: 15]

```
struct GridPosition {

    var col: Int = 0
    var row: Int = 0
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var backgroundLayer = SKNode()
    private var tileLayer = SKNode()
    private var gridSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    private var gridRows: Int = 0
    private var gridCols: Int = 0
    private var gridBlanks = [Int]()
    private var tiles = [[Tile]]()
    var tileSize: CGFloat = 150

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        backgroundLayer.zPosition = 1
        addChild(backgroundLayer)

        tileLayer.zPosition = 2
        addChild(tileLayer)

        gridRows = 8
        gridCols = 11
        gridBlanks = [0,1,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,31,32,33,36,40,43,56,64,67,69,70,71,72,73,75,77,78,79,82,85,86,87]

        createGrid()

        createBackgroundTiles()
    }

    func createGrid() {

        for row in 0 ..< gridRows {

            var rowContent = [Tile]()

            for col in 0 ..< gridCols {

                let currentTileLocation: Int = row * gridCols + col
                var tile: Tile

                if gridBlanks.contains(currentTileLocation) {
                    tile = Tile(row: row, col: col, type: .blank, tileSize: tileSize)
                }
                else {
                    tile = Tile(row: row, col: col, type: .regular, tileSize: tileSize)
                }

                tile.position = positionInGrid(column: col, row: row)
                tile.zPosition = CGFloat(100 + gridRows - row)
                tileLayer.addChild(tile)
                rowContent.append(tile)
            }

            tiles.append(rowContent)
        }
    }

    func tileByGridPosition(_ gridPos: GridPosition) -> Tile {
        return (tiles[Int(gridPos.row)][Int(gridPos.col)])
    }

    func positionInGrid(column: Int, row: Int) -> CGPoint {

        let startX = 0 - CGFloat(gridCols / 2) * tileSize
        let startY = 0 - CGFloat(gridRows / 2) * tileSize + tileSize / 2

        return CGPoint(

            x: startX + CGFloat(column) * tileSize,
            y: startY + CGFloat(row) * tileSize)
    }

    func createBackgroundTiles() {

        for row in 0...gridRows {

            for col in 0...gridCols {

                let topLeft = (col > 0) && (row < gridRows) && tileByGridPosition(GridPosition(col: col - 1, row: row)).type == .regular
                let bottomLeft = (col > 0) && (row > 0) && tileByGridPosition(GridPosition(col: col - 1, row: row - 1)).type == .regular
                let topRight = (col < gridCols) && (row < gridRows) && tileByGridPosition(GridPosition(col: col, row: row)).type == .regular
                let bottomRight = (col < gridCols) && (row > 0) && tileByGridPosition(GridPosition(col: col, row: row - 1)).type == .regular

                // The tiles are named from 0 to 15, according to the bitmask that is made by combining these four values.
                let value = Int(NSNumber(value: topLeft)) | Int(NSNumber(value: topRight)) << 1 | Int(NSNumber(value: bottomLeft)) << 2 | Int(NSNumber(value: bottomRight)) << 3

                // Values 0 (no tiles)
                if value != 0 {

                    var gridPosition = positionInGrid(column: col, row: row)
                    gridPosition.x -= tileSize / 2
                    gridPosition.y -= tileSize / 2

                    let backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ("background_tile_\(value)"))
                    backgroundNode.size = CGSize(width: tileSize, height: tileSize)
                    backgroundNode.alpha = 0.8
                    backgroundNode.position = gridPosition
                    backgroundNode.zPosition = 1
                    backgroundLayer.addChild(backgroundNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Tile: SKSpriteNode {

    private var row = 0
    private var col = 0
    var type: TileType = .blank

    init(row: Int, col: Int, type: TileType, tileSize: CGFloat) {

        super.init(texture: nil ,color: .clear, size:CGSize(width: tileSize, height: tileSize))

        self.type = type
        size = self.size

        let square = SKSpriteNode(color: type.color, size: size)
        square.zPosition = 1
        addChild(square)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to mind is when one node touches another node, at that moment in time evaluate the display of said node, as well as change the neighbors that are affected by it.